# program is to remove zeroes in the last of a number example:if my number is 1200 the output must be 12 its not working with 8000

Tags: c

my program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()    
{   
  int num, count = 0, i, x;

  scanf ("%d", &num);

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)    
  {    
      if (num % 10 == 0)   
      {    
          num = num / 10;
          count++;    
      }    
      x = 10 ^ count;

      if (num % x == 0)    
     {    
           num = num / x;    
     }
  }    
   printf ("%d", num);  

  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You do know that `^` is a xor operation not a power?

Comment: Next time please read the fine manual before asking http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.11 (or a good C book if you think the original stuff it too tough). Oh, and read [ask], as it stands there is no question asked.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to divide by 10 as long as the number has no remainder on division by 10.

So in essence:

```
scanf("%u", &num);
while (0 == (num % 10)){
      num/=10;
}
printf("%u\n", num);
```

It's also recommended to check for the output value 1 of `scanf` so that you know you've converted 1 decimal unsigned (`%u`) number. Of course `num` should be declared `unsigned int num` unless you allow for negative inputs. You need no extra variables etc. The usage of `^`, which is a bitwise xor operator (not a power operator) is nonsensical.

Comment: This code invokes undefined behaviour. Check the type of `num`. And don't use Yoda conditions, they are just obfuscation.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite The Yoda conditions I like. To avoid errors I use them.

Comment: They don't agoid errors, expecially not here, And modern compilers warn about the `=` v. `==` problem since more than 20 years. Yoda died in the 80ies  Write clear and human readable code. And enable&fix all warnings. Said that, your code still invokes UB.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I did warn about the changed declaration. The OP probably wants to work on positive integers anyway.

Comment: We can't know. OP did not even ask a question. This is not a speculation site, nor a coding service. We should wait until OP clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need these much complications to solve this problem .This can be solved simply by :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num, rem;

  scanf("%d", &num);

  rem = num % 10;
  while (rem == 0)      // till last digit is non-zero
  {
    num = num / 10;     // removes last digit
    rem = num % 10;
  }
  printf("%d", num);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:-**

```
1200
12

8000
8
```

Comment: I’m not convinced that the variable `rem` is necessary; you can simply use `num % 10` in the condition.  It also isn’t clear why you use a counted `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.